# Customize workitem (bug) and add 'Field' to top group of workitem in TFS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-workitem, workitem

I am trying to customize workitem (bug) and replace 'Area' with 'Team' in workitem UI in TFS.

I was following below documentation to achieve this.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/use-team-fields-instead-area-paths?view=tfs-2018&viewFallbackFrom=vsts
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/weblayout-xml-elements?view=tfs-2018

However I found that weblayout  configuration of workitems (e.g. bug) are not clear. As per the below screenshot (from documentation), it looks like I can add control to section where status/ reason available, but in reality I cannot add this because these controls available under "SystemControls". My requirement is replacing area with team .

[image]

If you have experienced/ tried similar scenario, Can you provide more specific example on this?.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of TFS do you use?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk TFS 2017

Answer (score 1):

Although https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/xml/weblayout-xml-elements?view=tfs-2017 says that `Replaces` only works in 2018, we use it in 2017 Update 3.

```
<Control Label="Team" Type="FieldControl" FieldName="Fabrikam.Team" Replaces="System.Areay" />
```

You probably also need to do this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/use-team-fields-instead-area-paths?view=tfs-2017 but I haven't tested that. We use a Team field alongside Area

Answer (score 0):

Area is a **required** field in all TFS work items. You can't replace it or remove it as *work items will not function properly without it*.